# Is it recommended to use XAMPP(software bundle) on production environment and why?

Tags: lamp

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29

Using it will save lots of time, though...

Answer (score 1):

it is not recommended because the Xammp stack is not secure by default from the website

> The philosophy behind XAMPP is to build an easy to install distribution for developers to >get into the world of Apache. To make it convenient for developers XAMPP is configured with >all features turned on.
>
> The default configuration is not good from a securtiy point of view and it's not secure >enough for a production environment - please don't use XAMPP in such environment.
>
> Since LAMPP 0.9.5 you can make your XAMPP installation secure by calling »/opt/lampp/lampp >security

Therefore if you use this on a production site it will get hacked. As maxwell says you would do well to learn how to configure and setup your own LAMP.

It is not that hard, from a tutorial side the following [site](http://howtoforge.com/) will give you a start and for everything else theres always google or post a more specific question here

Comment: +1 for citing XAMPP's own line on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend it, you'll better roll up your Apache/PHP/MySQL stack yourself, that way you'll have full control of what's loaded, and as it is for production use, you'll learn by the way the inner workings of your setup and will be able to document it.